# Error during tflite-model-maker installation on google colab

Tags: python, tflite

I was trying to install tflite-model-maker on my google colab using following statement.

`!pip install -q tflite-model-maker`

& `!pip install -q tflite-model-maker-nightly`

But both statement finally show a error while installing the dependencies. And here it is:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Now what can i do to resolve  this issue or suggest me a alternative.